# Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMDocument::saveXML() must be an instance of DOMNode, string

Tags: php, xml

I'm having a problem when saving the data into XML when there's no existing XML like `orders.xml`. But when there is existing file it saves. It shows

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMDocument::saveXML() must be an instance of DOMNode, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\CWP413\MidtermExam\buy.php on line 75"...

The first line is for loading the form from buying the product from another form.

Here is my code:

```
// script by candy21  
$products =simplexml_load_file("product.xml") or die("ERROR");

foreach ($products->product as $product){
        if($product['id']==$_GET['id']){
            $id = $product['id'];
            $name =$product->name;
            $price = $product->price;
            break;
        }

    }


if(isset($_POST['submitSave'])){
    $quan = $_POST['quan'];

    $total = $price * $quan;

    $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
    $xml -> preserveWhiteSpace = TRUE;
    $xml -> formatOutput = true;

    if(file_exists("orders.xml")){
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('orders.xml');
        $order = $xml->addChild('order');
        $order->addChild('id', $id);
        $order->addChild('name', $name);
        $order->addChild('price', $price);
        $order->addChild('quan', $quan);
        $order->addChild('total', $total);

        //echo "<xmp>" .$xml -> saveXML(). "</xmp>";
        $xml->saveXML("orders.xml");
        $xml=simplexml_load_file("orders.xml") or die("ERROR");
        $a=1;
        foreach($xml->children() as $order)
        {
        echo"<div class = 'orderlist' ";
        echo"<b>Order No.:". $a++."</b><br>";
        echo"Product Id: ".$order->id."<br>";
        echo"Product Name: ".$order->name."<br>";
        echo"Price: ".$order->price."<br>";
        echo"Quantity Ordered: ".$order->quan."<br>";
        echo"Total Price: ".$order->total."<br>";
        echo"</div><br>";
        }

    }
    else{
        $orders = $xml -> createElement("orders");
        $xml -> appendChild($orders);

        $order = $xml -> createElement("order");
        $orders -> appendChild($order);

        $id = $xml -> createElement("id", $id);
        $order -> appendChild($id);



        $name = $xml -> createElement("name", $name);
        $order -> appendChild($name);

        $price = $xml -> createElement("price", $price);
        $order -> appendChild($price);

        $quan = $xml -> createElement("quan", $quan);
        $order -> appendChild($quan);

        $total = $xml -> createElement("total", $total);
        $order -> appendChild($total);

        $xml->saveXML("orders.xml");
        $xml->saveXML($order->item(0));

        $xml=simplexml_load_file("orders.xml") or die("ERROR");
        $a=1;
        foreach($xml->children() as $order)
        {
        echo"<div class = 'orderlist' ";
        echo"<b>Order No.:".$a++."</b><br>";
        echo"Product Id: ".$order->id."<br>";
        echo"Product Name: ".$order->name."<br>";
        echo"Price: ".$order->price."<br>";
        echo"Quantity Ordered: ".$order->quan."<br>";
        echo"Total Price: ".$order->total."<br>";
        echo"</div><br>";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DOMDocument::saveXML()` doesn't take a filename argument. It returns the result as a string, you need to write that to the file yourself. So change:

```
$xml->saveXML("orders.xml");
```

to:

```
file_put_contents("orders.xml", $xml->saveXML());
```

Comment: Or just `$xml->save("orders.xml")`